# Perl OO - Creating a list of objects

Tags: perl, oop, object, hash

I have a package that creates a Document object:

```
package Document;

sub new
{
    my ($class, $id) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    $self = {
        _id => $id,
        _title => (),
        _words => ()
    };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
    }

sub pushWord{
    my ($self, $word) = @_;
    if(exists $self->{_words}{$word}){
        $self->{_words}{$word}++;
    }else{
        $self->{_words}{$word} = 0;
    }
}
```

I call it:

```
my @docs;

while(counter here){
    my $doc = Document->new();
    $doc->pushWord("qwe");
    $doc->pushWord("asd");
    push(@docs, $doc);
}
```

At the first iteration, the first `$doc`'s hash has two elements. At the second iteration, the second `$doc`'s hash has four elements (inluding two from the first one). But when I used that entity object (create an array of `Document`), I get:

- Document-1 with hash size of x
- Document-2 with hash size of x+y
- Document-3 with hash size of x+y+z

Why is the size of the hash incrementing? Document-3 has all the hash contents in Document-1 and Document-2. Does this have something to do with blessing or undefining the variable?  Is the constructor wrong?

Thanks :D

Comment: What do you mean by "hash size"?

Comment: oh sorry if it doesn't clear. What I mean is the total element of a hash. So the Document-2's hash have all the element of the Document-1's hash.

Comment: That isn't the behaviour I get. Your constructor is definitely wrong, but please show your calling code as well.

Comment: edited with the simplification of how I call it.
The idea is that I want to count the frequency of every word in every document.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two main problems

- Your initialisation of `$self`

  ```
  $self = {
      _id => $id,
      _title => (),
      _words => ()
  };
  ```

  is very wrong, because the empty parentheses `()` add nothing to the structure. If I dump  `$self` after this I get

  ```
  { _id => 1, _title => "_words" }
  ```

  You are also blessing `$self` twice, but there is no problem with that: it is more of an indication that you don't understand what you're doing.
- There is no need to initialise a hash element for the first occurrence of a word: Perl will do that for you. In addition you should be initialising the count to `1` and not to `0`.

Here's an example of your code working as it should. I have used `Data::Dump` to display the contents of the three document objects.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Document;

sub new {
    my ($class, $id) = @_;

    my $self = {
        _id => $id,
        _words => {},
    };

    bless $self, $class;
}

sub pushWord {
    my ($self, $word) = @_;

    ++$self->{_words}{$word};
}



package main;

use Data::Dump;

my $doc1 = Document->new(1);
my $doc2 = Document->new(2);
my $doc3 = Document->new(3);

$doc1->pushWord($_) for qw/ a b c /;
$doc2->pushWord($_) for qw/ d e f /;
$doc3->pushWord($_) for qw/ g h i /;

use Data::Dump;

dd $doc1;
dd $doc2;
dd $doc3;
```

**output**

```
bless({ _id => 1, _words => { a => 1, b => 1, c => 1 } }, "Document")
bless({ _id => 2, _words => { d => 1, e => 1, f => 1 } }, "Document")
bless({ _id => 3, _words => { g => 2, h => 2, i => 2 } }, "Document")
```

Comment: It solves my problem, and you also teach me how to use `Data::Dump`. Thanks for answering a question from a newbie like me :D